# Почему в mapper изменяется тип данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

У меня есть две вьюхи в Postres (пример):

```
CREATE VIEW public.valueint_view AS
 SELECT valueint.idvalfield,         // UUID
        valueint.valueint AS value   // Integer
 FROM valueint;

CREATE VIEW public.valuetext_view AS
 SELECT valuetext.idvalfield,        // UUID
    valuetext.valuetext AS value     // Text
   FROM valuetext;
```

С помощью SQLALchemy я описываю для них модели. И указываю, что в каждом отображение поле `value` имеет тип **Text**.

```
t_value_int = Table(
    'valueint_view', metadata,
    Column('idvalfield', postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,),
    Column('value', Text)
)

t_value_text = Table(
    'valuetext_view', metadata,
    Column('idvalfield', postgresql.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True,),
    Column('value', Text)
)
```

Но, когда я использую `UNION_ALL` в SQLAlchemy, получаю ошибку:

```
2020-01-21 10:52: 40,475 error [cid.exceptions.controllers.exceptions: 22] [waitress] sqlalchemy.excavation.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.mistakes.DatatypeMismatch) ERROR: при построении union невозможно обобщить типы integer и text
```

Проверил в дебаг режиме. Запрос совершаю к моделям имеющим тип **Text**, но при получение результат из них из таблицы `valueint_view` получаю **Integer**, а не ожидаемый мной **Text**

Почему так происходит? Ведь маппер должен был отобразить данные в том типе, которй я указал при описании модели.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете объединить две таблицы, ряд данных которых отличается.

```
valueint.valueint AS value
```

и

```
valuetext.valuetext AS value
```

Это разные типы данных, и ошибка говорит об этом однозначно:

> ERROR: при построении union невозможно обобщить типы integer и text

Comment: На ОРМ не знает что за тип у меня в самой таблице. Маппер без проблем должен int преобразовывать в указанный мной Text

Comment: ORM не знает, а база данных знает. Посмотрите запрос, который генерит ORM, все поймете.